# clang address sanitizer fails to find a use after free

Tags: c, clang, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use **clang address sanitizer** like [this link](http://releases.llvm.org/3.4/tools/clang/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) with the following example where **rel_filename** points to somewhere inside a freed buffer, and when I send it to printf nothing bad happens.
Does it make sense?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *dir;
    char *abs_filename;
    char *rel_filename;

    abs_filename = (char *) malloc( strlen(argv[1]) + 1 );
    strcpy( abs_filename, argv[1] );

    if (strchr( abs_filename, '/' ))
    {
        char *tmp = strrchr( abs_filename, '/' );
        dir = (char *) malloc( tmp-abs_filename+1 );
        *tmp = 0;
        strcpy( dir, abs_filename );
        rel_filename = tmp+1;
        free(abs_filename);
    }
    else
    {
        rel_filename = abs_filename;
        dir = NULL;
    }

    if (dir)          printf("directory is: %s\n",dir);
    if (rel_filename) printf("filenmae  is: %s\n",rel_filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I compile and invoke the code:

```
$ clang -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -c main.c -o main.o
```

Then I link with clang:

```
$ clang -g -fsanitize=address main.o -o main
```

Then I run and everything goes fine when it should really crash right?

```
$ ./main /home/oren/ggg.txt
directory is: /home/oren
filenmae  is: ggg.txt
```

What's going on?

Here is the clang version:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_342/final 322618)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 (LTS) 64 bit
```

Comment: Well, undefined behavior is undefined, anything can happen, right.

Comment: The memory itself doesn't just "disappear", and is most likely still mapped to your process. It is however UB to try and access it.

Comment: I understand that this is UB, but how come clang address sanitizer doesn't report this use-after-free scenario?

Comment: Both `clang` 4 and `valgrind` report it for me with your compilation options and command line arguments.

Comment: Are you running it with `./a.out /home/oren/ggg.txt`? `./main` should not exist if linking with the command, you provided.

Comment: @ks1322 thanks, I've added the -o main missing.

Comment: I could not reproduce it on Fedora 28. This is probably OS specific bug. It is worth to post your OS and clang version as well.

Comment: Added clang version (3.4.2) and OS (Ubuntu 14.04.5)

Answer (score 1):

The version of clang you're using is quite old -- [it was released in June 2014.](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-announce/2014-June/000053.html) Current versions of clang have a more robust memory sanitizer which is able to catch this issue.